# SSIS error connecting to Excel Source

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, sql-server-2012-datatools

I have a 64 bit machine.

One of my projects I have the properties of the project for Run64BitRunTime = False and I still get the following error when attaching to an Excel xlsx source in order to import into SQL 2012.

Error   1

```
Validation error. Data Flow Task: Package1: The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered. If the 32-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 64-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".      Package1.dtsx   0   0
```

Error   2

```
Validation error. Data Flow Task: Package1: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=219816     Package1.dtsx   0   0
```

Comment: try https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed the following (32 bit)

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255